# Apply oData filter on IQueryable throws ODataException Could not find property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, odata

I'm using Entity Framework with OData, Having two classes like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public virtual B b {get; set;}
}
public class B {
    public int c {get; set;}
}
```

Executing query like this from the dbSet:

```
 var query = Foos.Where(x => x.id == 1)
```

And having the following oData : `(B/c eq 3)`

Apply filter on the IQueryable result (query):

```
FilterQueryOption filter = new FilterQueryOption(queryFilter, ODataQueryContext);
var q = filter.ApplyTo(query, new ODataQuerySettings());
```

Throws oDataException with message: Could not find a property named b on type Foo

Comment: Perhaps its confusing it with `System.Type`? Try renaming your class `Type` to something else.

Comment: This is a toy code to explain my problem, it's not the real class name in our code. I can rename it for the clarity of my question to Foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Foo
{ 
    [ForeignKey("B")]
    public int c { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The code is generated by Entity Framework (database first) and I cannot modify it.

Comment: Does the foreign key relationship exist in the database?

Comment: No, not at all. I understand what you mean and you are all right but I can't modify the DB, I'll ask my team leader. Thank you.